# Files over a certain size return 404 in Swashbuckle.Swagger endpoint with IOperationFilter file upload

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

There appears to be a file-size limitation when using the Swagger UI when using an upload file parameter. I'm not sure where that limit is (chrome,swagger,web api), but the file I've been given to test with is 61.9 MB (64,913,408 bytes).

I have tried setting the max length property on the parameter to zero, 75000000, left to default.

My file parameter:

```
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {

        if (operation == null) return;

        var fileParm = new Parameter
        {
            description = "File Upload",
            name = "file",
            @in = "formData",
            required = true,
            type = "file",
            maxLength = 75000000
        };

        if (operation.operationId == "Brands_InsertData")
        {
            if (!operation.parameters.Any())
            {
                operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();
            }
            operation.parameters.Add(fileParm);
            operation.consumes.Add("multipart/form-data");
        }
    }
```

My endpoint:

```
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> InsertData()
    {
        BrandDataInsertReport result;
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("content");
        }
        using (var stream = await FileStreamUtilities.ReadLargeStreamAsync(Request))
        {
            result = GetMockResponse();
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result, JsonSerializerUtilities.IsoOverrideFormatter());
    }
```

The file this endpoint needs to consume are pretty large, but over a certain size (say around five meg?) I start getting a 404 error instead hitting the endpoint on hitting submit.

Comment: Have you tried without the swagger-ui, with fiddler or postman ?

Comment: `maxLength` won't have any effect here, as it only applies to `type: string` parameters but not `type: file`.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Just did at your suggestion. Postman returns a 404 as well. And fiddler catches the traffice as 404/not found. Smaller files work.

Comment: OK. I've got it. Thanks @HelderSepulveda for setting me on the path that ruled out Swagger and the parameter. I'll answer my own question when the timer lets me :) but it required setting the express server to allow the larger binary.

<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="75000000" />